# RDF--How do I make a transitive property shift, based on the rdf:type?

Tags: rdf, owl, sesame, blazegraph

I'm trying to find a way to infer/propogate a property based on types to prevent name collision:

```
:AOrder :Store :AStore ;
        a :OrderType ;
        :user :AUser .

:AStore :name "Store Name";
        a :StoreType

:AUser :name "Some User";
       a :UserType
```

Based on the triples above, I'd like to infer several other triples:

```
:AOrder :storeName "Store Name" .
:AOrder :userName "Some User" .
```

How can I do this?  FYI, I'm currently using Bigdata and Sesame.

One way would be to use SPIN, but it doesn't seem like Bigdata + Sesame have it; it looks like Jena is the only thing out there with something comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could express this using a SPARQL update operation:

```
INSERT { 
  ?x :storeName ?store_name ; 
     :userName ?user_name . 
 }
 WHERE { 
  ?x a :OrderType;
     :Store [ :name ?store_name ] ;
     :user [ :name ?user_name ] .
 }
```

Execute this operation whenever your store is updated (if you're working locally you can use a [RepositoryListener](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/api/index.html?org/openrdf/repository/event/package-summary.html) to intercept change events) and the triples you want will be inserted.

Alternatively, look at some of the custom reasoning tools available for Sesame. I'm not sure Bigdata supports a custom reasoner, but you could have a look at [this custom rule-based reasoner extension](http://jeenbroekstra.blogspot.com/2009/10/simple-rules-using-construct-queries-in.html) (although it's slightly out of date). Or take a look at [OWLIM](http://www.ontotext.com/owlim), which is a Sesame backend with OWL reasoning capabilities, which also supports custom rules.

Comment: Thanks for your reply-I ended up going with Jena + Jena Rules.  But anyway, do you know how the custom reasoner you posted deals with entailment/reasoned triples?  Does it just add everything to the existing store, making it impossible to tell what's inferred and what's base data?

Comment: No, because first of all Sesame supports a distinction between explicit and inferred triples at the API level, so you will always be able to keep tell which is which. In addition, the custom reasoner uses a separate context for inferred triples.